# jQuery: Finding all elements that contain a string, including attribute values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to scan a page and find every innermost element containing any reference to a specified keyword. Currently, I am using the following code to search the elements:

```
$(':contains('+currentKeyword+'):not(:has(:contains('+currentKeyword+')))');
```

This works great for elements with text containing the keyword, but this approach does not consider the attributes of each keyword when searching. I would like it to select every element that has an attribute containing currentKeyword so it doesn't miss images with alt attributes and links and so forth. How can I accomplish this without making the code too messy?

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
function findKeyword() {
  return $(this).html().indexOf(currentKeyword) !== -1;
}

$('*').filter(findKeyword).filter(function () {
  return !$(this).children().filter(findKeyword).length;
}
```